# Calculating the sum of prime numbers

Tags: c, function, for-loop, primes

Can anyone tell me what is the problem here, considering I'm a beginner here? It is not showing Runtime error or something.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int checkPrime(int n){
       for (int i = 2; i * i < n; i++) {
        if(n % i == 0 && i!=n)
            return 0;
    }
    return n;
}

int main(){
    int t; 
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t--){
        int n,sum=0; 
        scanf("%d",&n);
        for(int i=n;i>1;i--){
              if ( checkPrime(i) != 0 )
              sum += i;
        }
        printf("%d\n",sum);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at this. It sounds like you could use help debugging. What development environment or toolchain are you using? (gcc, MSVC, etc.) That will help us recommend a debugger. https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Also, specify what input you're giving your program, what the expected output is, and what the actual output is. Use the minimal set of input that still generates the problem. [example]

Comment: What's the maximum value `n` may take?

Comment: @SparKot N<=10^6

Comment: @ssd I'm sorry that I didn't write here but I have already corrected it and initialized it from 2. But, my answer is wrong.

Comment: Use a debugger. People here can do debugging in their mind, but asking them to do that will not help you learn.

Comment: @AniketMann if you're supposed to add the first `n` primes, your `main` doesn't do that; you add the first `n` numbers, except for non-primes zero is added instead of `n`, because `checkPrime` returns zero. You need to track a count of how many primes you find (starting at 2), and only stop when that count reaches `n`.

Comment: And, what's the maximum value `t` may take?

Comment: Aniket Mani, Post input used, output seen and output expected that exhibited a problem.

Answer (score 0):

In `checkPrime`, you have a loop

```
for(int i=0;i*i<n;i++){
    if(n%i==0){
```

But in the first iteration, you have `i=0` and then `n%i`, but mod 0 is undefined behavior in C. I think what you want is

```
for (i = 2; i * i <= n; i++)
```

UPDATE: In `checkPrime`, you can eliminate `count` entirely, as follows:

```
int checkPrime(int n) {
    for (int i = 2; i * i <= n; i++) {
        if(n % i == 0)
            return 0;
    }
    return n;
}
```

This way, as soon as you find a divisor, you know the number isn't prime so you just return a 0. If you get all the way through the loop, then no divisor was found so the number is prime.

Comment: @ I have already realised this problem and corrected it but the output iis wrong

Comment: @AniketMani What is the input? What is the output? What should the output be?

Comment: Shouldn't the upper bound of that loop be `i*i <= n` (not `<`)? With strict less-than, squares of primes will be reported as prime.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. the first line of input contains the value of `t`. 2nd line has input `n=10` but the output is 30. But it should be 17?

Comment: Sorry, @nielsen, you are right. That is the other bug.

Answer (score 0):

OP's `checkPrime()` has various troubles.

```
int checkPrime(int n){
       for (int i = 2; i * i < n; i++) {
        if(n % i == 0 && i!=n)
            return 0;
    }
    return n;
}
```

**Wrong limit** [@John Bollinger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71396655/calculating-the-sum-of-prime-numbers#comment126197994_71396803)

`i * i < n;` --> `i * i <= n;`

**Risks overflow**

`i * i` overflows when `n` is a prime near `INT_MAX`.

**Returns non-zero (is a prime) for non-primes**

`checkPrime(1)`, `checkPrime(negative values)` should return 0.

**Useless code**

`i!=n` in `if(n % i == 0 && i!=n)` is not needed.

**Repaired**

```
int checkPrime(int n){
  for (int i = 2; i <= n/i; i++) {
    if (n % i == 0) {
      return 0;
    }
  }
  return n > 1;
}
```

**Sum may overflow**

```
//int n,sum=0;
...
//sum += i;
...
//printf("%d\n",sum);

int n;
long long sum=0;
...
sum += i;
...
printf("%lld\n", sum);
```

**OP's overall code may have additional issues.**